# Creating RDS Proxy and RDS Cluster with CDK fails the first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-rds-proxy

I'm trying to create a DB stack, it has and RDS Cluster, and RDS Proxy and some other stuff.
When I first run *cdk deploy* always fails half way with the following message:

```
Embedded stack 
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:####:stack/MainStack-DBNestedStackDBNestedStackResource####/### 
was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [memcachedApp, Parameters6795E5B4, DatabaseproxyIAMRole7D0578A1].
```

If I run again *cdk deploy* it works.

I'm trying to find out what is causing the error but I don't know where to look and because the ROLLBACK start immediately, I can't see any more errors.

Do you know if there is something I missing?

Comment: Go to CloudFormation console. Find your stack, then check its Events for details.

Comment: Yes, thank you, from there is where I got the error I posted.